# Lock-free atomic shared pointer in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, template, lock-free, atomic

I'm trying to write a lock-free implementation for [atomic shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr). Basically, there are two class templates `shared_ptr` and `atomic_shared_ptr`, each implemented in a header file of its own, for a total of two header files. The algorithm is inspired by the split reference counts idea used to implement a lock-free stack in [*C++ Concurrency in Action*](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action) Sect. 7.2.4. This is my first time designing and writing lock-free algorithms, and I'm not confident. I want to have my code reviewed for possible flaws in the algorithm (quite likely ~>_<~) and room for improvement. Note that

1. I don't intend to faithfully follow the interface specified by the standard/draft, because it's too cumbersome. Specifically, I didn't implement some methods and modified the signature of some others.
2. Refining memory order requirements is left to future work.

### Code

**shared_ptr.hpp** ([view](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/master/lf/shared_ptr.hpp) on GitHub for better syntax highlighting)

```
namespace shared_ptr_impl {

// cnt encodes both reference count and staged reference count.
// Staged reference count is used to support atomic_shared_ptr.
// *this can be deleted iff both reach zero.
// Specifically, cnt = (staged reference count) * 2^32 + (reference count).
// So long as reference count < 2^32, the two should not interfere with each other.
// Use unsigned type to wrap-around and avoid overflow.
// Encodes the two into a single 64-bit variable cnt, so that operations on the two
// can be made a single atomic operation on cnt.
// pdata is only modified at construction/destruction.
// This struct is therefore thread-safe.
template <typename T>
struct block {
  std::unique_ptr<T> pdata;
  std::atomic_uint64_t cnt;
};

} // namespace shared_ptr_impl

template <typename T>
class shared_ptr {
  template <typename U>
  friend class atomic_shared_ptr;

  using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
  using block = shared_ptr_impl::block<T>;

public:
  // copy control
  shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& p):
    pblock(p.pblock) {
    if (pblock) ++pblock->cnt;
  }

  shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& p) noexcept:
    pblock(std::exchange(p.pblock, nullptr)) {
    // pass
  }

  shared_ptr& operator=(shared_ptr p) noexcept {
    swap(*this, p);
    return *this;
  }

 ~shared_ptr() {
    if (pblock) {
      if (--pblock->cnt == 0) delete pblock;
    }
  }

  friend void swap(shared_ptr& a, shared_ptr& b) {
    std::swap(a.pblock, b.pblock);
  }

  // construct
  shared_ptr(T* p = nullptr):
    pblock(!p ? nullptr : new block{unique_ptr(p), {1}}) {
    // pass
  }

  // modifier
  void reset(T* p = nullptr) {
    auto expire(std::move(*this));
    pblock = !p ? nullptr : new block{unique_ptr(p), {1}};
  }

  // observer
  T* get() const {
    return !pblock ? nullptr : pblock->pdata.get();
  }

  T& operator*() const {
    assert(*this);
    return *pblock->pdata;
  }

  T* operator->() const {
    assert(*this);
    return get();
  }

  explicit operator bool() const {
    return pblock;
  }

  bool is_lock_free() const {
    assert(*this);
    return pblock->cnt.is_lock_free();
  }

private:
  shared_ptr(block* p):
    pblock(p) {
    // pass
  }

  block* pblock;
};
```

**atomic_shared_ptr.hpp** ([view](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free/blob/master/lf/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp) on GitHub)

```
namespace atomic_shared_ptr_impl {

using shared_ptr_impl::block;

// Works with block.
// Actual staged reference count = stagecnt / one_stagecnt (i.e., uint64_t(1) << 32).
template <typename T>
struct counted_ptr {
  std::uint64_t stagecnt;
  block<T>* pblock;
};

} // namespace atomic_shared_ptr_impl

template <typename T>
class atomic_shared_ptr {
  using shared_ptr_t = shared_ptr<T>;
  using counted_ptr = atomic_shared_ptr_impl::counted_ptr<T>;
  static constexpr auto one_stagecnt = std::uint64_t(1) << 32;

public:
  // copy control
  atomic_shared_ptr(const atomic_shared_ptr&) = delete;
  atomic_shared_ptr& operator=(const atomic_shared_ptr&) = delete;
 ~atomic_shared_ptr() {
    auto p = pblock.load();
    if (p.pblock) {
      p.pblock->cnt += p.stagecnt;
      shared_ptr_t(p.pblock);
    }
  }

  // construct
  atomic_shared_ptr():
    pblock{} {
    // pass
  }

  atomic_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t p):
    pblock{0, std::exchange(p.pblock, nullptr)} {
    // pass
  }

  // modify
  void operator=(shared_ptr_t p) {
    counted_ptr newp{0, std::exchange(p.pblock, nullptr)};
    auto oldp = pblock.exchange(newp);
    if (oldp.pblock) {
      oldp.pblock->cnt += oldp.stagecnt;
      p.pblock = oldp.pblock;
    }
  }

  shared_ptr_t exchange(shared_ptr_t p) {
    counted_ptr newp{0, std::exchange(p.pblock, nullptr)};
    auto oldp = pblock.exchange(newp);
    if (oldp.pblock) oldp.pblock->cnt += oldp.stagecnt;
    return oldp.pblock;
  }

  bool compare_exchange_weak(shared_ptr_t& expect, const shared_ptr_t& desire) {
    auto oldp = copy_ptr();
    if (oldp.pblock != expect.pblock) {
      expect = oldp.pblock;
      return false;
    }
    counted_ptr newp{0, desire.pblock};
    if (pblock.compare_exchange_strong(oldp, newp)) {
      if (oldp.pblock) oldp.pblock->cnt += oldp.stagecnt - 2;
      if (desire) ++desire.pblock->cnt;
      return true;
    }
    if (expect) --expect.pblock->cnt;
    return false;
  }

  bool compare_exchange_weak(shared_ptr_t& expect, shared_ptr_t&& desire) {
    auto oldp = copy_ptr();
    if (oldp.pblock != expect.pblock) {
      expect = oldp.pblock;
      return false;
    }
    counted_ptr newp{0, desire.pblock};
    if (pblock.compare_exchange_strong(oldp, newp)) {
      if (oldp.pblock) oldp.pblock->cnt += oldp.stagecnt - 2;
      desire.pblock = nullptr;
      return true;
    }
    if (expect) --expect.pblock->cnt;
    return false;
  }

  bool compare_exchange_strong(shared_ptr_t& expect, const shared_ptr_t& desire) {
    auto p = expect.pblock;
    while (!compare_exchange_weak(expect, desire) && p == expect.pblock);
    return p == expect.pblock;
  }

  bool compare_exchange_strong(shared_ptr_t& expect, shared_ptr_t&& desire) {
    auto p = expect.pblock;
    while (!compare_exchange_weak(expect, std::move(desire)) && p == expect.pblock);
    return p == expect.pblock;
  }

  // observer
  bool is_lock_free() const {
    return pblock.is_lock_free();
  }

  operator shared_ptr_t() const {
    auto p = copy_ptr();
    return p.pblock;
  }

private:
  mutable std::atomic<counted_ptr> pblock;

  counted_ptr copy_ptr() const {
    counted_ptr p = pblock, pp;
    do {
      if (!p.pblock) return p;
      pp = p;
      pp.stagecnt += one_stagecnt;
    }
    while (!pblock.compare_exchange_weak(p, pp));
    pp.pblock->cnt += -one_stagecnt + 1;
    return pp;
  }
};
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I think the two .h files should be combined; They are intimately related.  Some demo code with a `main()` would help a lot, ideally with no assembly required.

Comment: @JiveDadson Agreed. i will consider adding some demo/test code later.

Comment: Hey there, this looks interesting but the github links are dead, can you post it somewhere else? Did you ever finish the demo code?

Comment: FYI, it looks like [this](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/lock_free) is the OP's github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Looks reasonable to me. But I strongly recommend splitting up some of the more complicated source lines to conform to the rule "one side effect, one line of code." For example:

```
if (--pblock->cnt == 0) delete pblock;
```

This really means

```
uint64_t new_cnt = --pblock->cnt;
if (new_cnt == 0) {
    delete pblock;
}
```

Or again:

```
void reset(T* p = nullptr) {
    auto expire(std::move(*this));
    pblock = !p ? nullptr : new block{unique_ptr(p), {1}};
}
```

This really means

```
void reset(T *p) {
    shared_ptr expire = std::move(*this);
    if (p != nullptr) {
        pblock = new block{unique_ptr(p), {1}};
    }
}
void reset() {
    shared_ptr expire = std::move(*this);
}
```

or possibly just

```
void reset(T *p) {
    swap(this, shared_ptr(p));
}
void reset() {
    reset(nullptr);
}
```

---

```
private:
  shared_ptr(block* p):
    pblock(p) {
    // pass
  }
```

Always, always, always mark your constructors `explicit`! This goes quadruple for implementation-detail private constructors.

In this case, because you failed to provide a `shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)` constructor, you won't be able to call

```
void foo(shared_ptr<Widget>);
void test() {
    foo(nullptr);
}
```

because there are two equally good ways of converting `nullptr` to `shared_ptr<Widget>` — via the public `T*` constructor and via the private `block*` constructor — and so you get an ambiguity. Marking the private constructor `explicit` would have solved that particular problem. However, you'll still need the constructor from `std::nullptr_t` (a.k.a. `decltype(nullptr)`) in order to solve

```
void foo(shared_ptr<Widget>);
void test() {
    foo(shared_ptr<Widget>(nullptr));
}
```

---

Your indentation of destructors by `n-1` characters is idiosyncratic and weird.

```
    foo();
   ~foo();  // Strange!
```

---

```
 ~atomic_shared_ptr() {
    auto p = pblock.load();
    if (p.pblock) {
      p.pblock->cnt += p.stagecnt;
      shared_ptr_t(p.pblock);
    }
  }
```

The line

```
      shared_ptr_t(p.pblock);
```

may be correct, but it certainly looks strange. I would also question the use of `auto` on your first line, given how important it is in this code that we know which of our variables are `atomic` and which aren't. So I would write this as

```
  ~atomic_shared_ptr() {
      counted_ptr p = pblock.load();
      if (p.pblock != nullptr) {
          std::atomic_uint64_t& cnt = p.pblock->cnt;
          cnt += p.stagecnt;
          std::uint64_t old_cnt = cnt--;
          if (old_cnt == 1) {
              delete p.pblock;
          }
      }
  }
```

And then I would wonder whether it was possible to coalesce those two additions into

```
      std::uint64_t new_cnt = (cnt += p.stagecnt - 1);
      if (new_cnt == 0) {
```

---

```
operator shared_ptr_t() const {
    auto p = copy_ptr();
    return p.pblock;
}
```

Again with the implicit conversion. `p.pblock` isn't a `shared_ptr<T>`, so it's strange to be returning it from a function that claims to return `shared_ptr<T>`. Eliminating that implicit conversion from `block*` to `shared_ptr` will force you to fix this too.

---

```
counted_ptr p = pblock, pp;
```

I strongly recommend writing one declaration per line.

```
counted_ptr p = pblock;
counted_ptr pp;
```

---

It seems like the bulk of the "interesting" stuff (and thus the highest likelihood of bugs) is in the `compare_exchange_weak` functions; and they depend on the `copy_ptr` function, which is non-standard (so cppreference won't help the reader understand its purpose) and undocumented. I strongly recommend adding some commentary to `copy_ptr` that explains what its preconditions and postconditions are supposed to be.